# AOL email attachment not present

Tags: aol-mail

I'm working with a user who has an Outlook 2013 account in addition to an AOL account. They sent an email with a .pdf and .pptx attachment from their Outlook account to their AOL account. In the AOL account, there's a paperclip so as to denote there is an attachment but once the email is opened, there is no attachment there. The user sent the same email from their Outlook 2013 email account to my Outlook 2013 account and I received it, attachments and all.

Is AOL stripping the attachment or do you think there's some other issue?

Comment: Isn't this a question that is better answered by AOL's support?

Comment: Valid point. I did research prior to posting this and several users stated AOL support was of no help when it came to this issue.